# Redirect users of a specific IP address

Tags: javascript, redirect, ip-address

I am making an IP approval system for my website, and I would like to, if the user has an IP address on the `banned` list, be redirected to `banned.html` on my site. I would like some JavaScript code for the head section on my website.

I know that a javascript redirect is...

```
window.location="banned.html";
```

But I am not sure of a function that returns the IP.

What code would I put in my head section to do this?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate, as it is asking how to incorporate a redirect into the IP detection.

EDIT: You can use JSON for the IP:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/?callback=?", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.ip);
    });
});
```

but how do I incorporate a redirect into this, based on if an IP is found on a list.

Comment: Most of the sites might be having dynamic IP's, what would you do in that case?

Comment: are you allowed to use ajax?

Comment: @shridhar yes I can use ajax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get client's IP address using javascript only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only)

Comment: Using javascript to enforce your ban is not recommended, users can easily turn off the javascript on their end. You should do your checks on the server side.

Comment: @ItayGal it is just to stop some kids from spamming my website - they probably don't know how to turn off javascript!

Comment: @DanielHarrin Kids are those people, who know the most about computers ;)

Comment: @HerrDerb yeah but these kids I am banning have nothing better to do with their time than swear in the comments of my website